# Why isn't AWS CloudFront updating my files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm new to AWS. 
But, I have an S3 Bucket containing a static website and it is hooked up to CloudFront. Originally, I had just a "under construction" HTML file. But since I removed it and actually added my website, I'm still seeing the old HTML.

If I browse to the cloudfront.net or the us-east-1.amazonaws.com I can see my full website. But its when I browse to my actual domain name when I see the old HTML.

I have changed the meta-data to to one hour and I also tried the same within CloudFront TTLs.

I also read that I had to invalidate my old file, which I did do but it doesnt seem to be doing anything.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I believe you have to clear the cache of your website, if it is cached on an edge. Only then will it retrieve the updated page.

Comment: Do an invalidation of your distribution using `/*` as the path.  After it completes, if that does not help, please capture the response headers from a request that shows the wrong response, and edit those into the question.